# Prove big O for a logarithmic function

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I am having a problem for proving the equation:

$ 5nlog_{2}{n} + 8n - 200$ is $O(n log_{2}{n})$

For this problem, I used this definition for Big O:

f(n) ∈ O(g(n)) if there exist constants c > 0 and n0 > 0 such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ c g(n) for all n ≥ n0.

First I write the equation as the Big O inequality:

$ 5nlog_{2}{n} + 8n - 200\le c * nlog_{2}{n}$

Then I divide both sides by $n log_{2}{n}$ to get

$5 + \frac{8}{log_{2}{n}} - \frac{200}{n log_{2}{n}} \le c, for $ n $\ge$2

Usually I take the coefficients of the left side to find c, but that results in a negative c, which is not allowed. This is where I'm stuck. Any help would be great.

Comment: Take $n_0$ such that the function positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious that

$$5n\log_2n\le cn\log_2n.$$

Also obvious that

$$8n\le cn\log_2n^*$$ because $8$ is a constant while $c\log_2n$ is growing.

And even more obvious that

$$-200\le cn\log_2n$$ as the LHS is negative.

$^*$For $n>1$.

Comment: How do you know their sum would hold the inequality as well? i mean if a < b and c < b is it necessary that a+c < b ?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui: review the definition of big-O.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of landau's notation (or "big O" notation) uses $|f(x)|$, not just $f(x)$.

So you actually have :

$$f = O(g) \Leftrightarrow \forall x>x_0,0\le |f(x)| \le C\cdot|g(x)|\Leftrightarrow \forall x>x_0,-C\cdot|g(x)| \le f(x) \le C\cdot|g(x)|$$

With $x_0$ an arbitrary element for which this holds true (meaning the big $O$ notation only "care" about what happens as $x\to+\infty$)

The important thing to remember here is that we use $|f(x)|$ just to get a better mental image of what the landau's notation mean, but you can always write it as the right side of the equivalence.